# How do I click on a row in a JQuery DataTable using HtmlUnit?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, htmlunit

I have a JQuery DataTable in one of my pages that, when a row is clicked, takes the user to a detail page for the row selected. I have the following configuration and it works.

```
if (tableConfig.rowClickEventHandler)
{
  table.on( 'select', function ( e, dt, type, indexes ) 
  {
    if (type === 'row')
    {
      tableConfig.rowClickEventHandler(table.rows(indexes).data().toArray());
    }
  });
}
```

Now what I'm trying to do is some browser testing of this functionality. I have tried this:

```
HtmlTableRow row = this.tableBody.getRows().get(x);
HtmlPage htmlPage = row.click();
```

Which seems to have no effect (stays on the same page). I then looked at the console in Firefox and saw that there is no "click" listener for a cell or a row, but there is one for the table body, so I tried this:

```
HtmlTableRow row = this.tableBody.getRows().get(x);
Event event = new MouseEvent(row, MouseEvent.TYPE_CLICK, false, false, false,
    MouseEvent.BUTTON_LEFT);
HtmlPage htmlPage = (HtmlPage)this.tableBody.click(event);
```

which also didn't work (stayed on the same page).

What's the proper way to get this to work?

Comment: Do you have a public page available to verify?

Comment: No, I do not. This is still only in development.

Comment: Too bad, i can only guess. Try to figure out if the event (at HTML level) is bound to the row or maybe to the cells or the cell content. Than try to click on this elements.

Comment: Just a note that I'm back on this problem. Maybe if I can set the X,Y of the MouseEvent, that will cause the table body listener to calculate which row that coordinate points to.

Comment: Can you please open an issue on github. It will be great if you can additionally a simple sampe html (e.g. similar to http://www.marcorpsa.com/ee/t2065.html) that matches your case.

Comment: I have opened an issue on github. I now have a public page for you to test on: http://photeus.com/campaigner-data/